# Make yaourt always use ABS for certain packages

Tags: archlinux

I wonder if yaourt can be set up to always use ABS (build form source) for certain packages (so they are built from sources even when performing full system upgrade: yaourt -Syua).

Something like BuildPkgs list in /etc/yaourtrc would come in handy, but I can't find anything like that.

Can anyone think of a way to do it?

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a workaround: you should install [customizepkg](http://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=10314) from AUR. Yaourt can use customizepkg so if you've a file named `foo` in `/etc/customizepkg.d/` package `foo` will built from source. If you don't want to change `foo`'s PKGBUILD `/etc/customizepkg.d/foo` can be an empty file.

So if you don't want change the PKGBUILDs you only need `touch /etc/customizepkg.d/package-build-from-source` to every package which you want to build from source.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for! Thank you.